# Is there any way to make this code simpler? I feel like there should be but I am very new to Python

Tags: python

```
def life():
    print("You wake up")
    eat = input("are you hungry? Please Enter y or n.")
    if eat.upper() == "Y":
        print("I predict you will eat breakfast")
    elif eat.upper() == "N":
        print("I predict you will skip breakfast")
    while eat.upper() not in ("Y","N"):
        print("input not accepted")
        eat = input("are you hungry? Please Enter y or n.")
        if eat.upper() == "Y":
            print("I predict you will eat breakfast")
        elif eat.upper() == "N":
            print("I predict you will skip breakfast")
    print("You leave the house")
    day = input("is it cloudy? please enter y or n")
    if day.upper() == "Y":
        print("I predict you will bring an umbrella")
    elif day.upper() == "N":
        print("I predict you will wear sunglasses")
    while day.upper() not in ("Y","N"):
        print("input not accepted")
        day = input("is it cloudy? please enter y or n")
        if day.upper() == "Y":
            print("I predict you will bring an umbrella")
        elif day.upper() == "N":
            print("I predict you will wear sunglasses")
    print("You go out for dinner")
    food = input("Do you want meat? please enter y or n")
    if food.upper() == "Y":
        print("I predict you will order steak!")
    elif food.upper() == "N":
        pass
    while food.upper() not in ("Y", "N"):
        print("input not accepted")
        food = input("Do you want meat? please enter y or n")
        if food.upper() == "Y":
            print("I predict you will order steak!")
        elif food.upper() == "N":
            pass
    pasta = input("Do you want Pasta: please enter y or n")
    if pasta.upper() == "Y":
        print("I predict you will order spaghetti and meatballs!!")
    elif pasta.upper() == "N":
        print("I predict you will order salad.")
    while pasta.upper() not in ("Y", "N"):
        print("input not accepted")
        pasta = input("Do you want Pasta: please enter y or n")
        if pasta.upper() == "Y":
            print("I predict you will order spaghetti and meatballs!!")
        elif pasta.upper() == "N":
            print("I predict you will order salad.")
life()
```

I feel like it is unnecessary to repeat multiple lines of code in the while statement. Is there any way to make the while statement go to a previous line of code and run it from there instead of re-entering the same code back into the while statement. The code seems to run fine but I would like it to be less clunky if possible.
Thanks!

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should be about a *specific* problem, with only the *shortest* code that demonstrates it included. As the terser comment above says, questions asking for general suggestions on how to improve *working* code belong on our sister site [codereview.se] instead (subject to its rules). See [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Create a function for taking input from the user and use it instead of all the while loops. Make the function take a parameter that is the prompt. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) to help you

Comment: I had some answer for you but unfortunately the 'trigger happy' people closed this question before I had a chance to post it.  Here: https://www.paste.org/103044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several modifications I would suggest.

1. Use [inline conditional statements](https://www.pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/) `<expression1> if <condition> else <expression2>`
2. Use string formatting `"Today is {}".format(date)`

So you can write

```py
s = "eat" if eat.upper() == "Y" else "skip" if eat.upper() == "N" else ""
print("I predict you will {} breakfast".format(s))
```

Be sure to check that `eat.upper()` is "Y" or "N" first, or the code would fail.

Since your code for `eat` and `day` are similar, you could also use a function to simplify your code.

Comment: Much better now. That said, do note the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point around questions that "require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions". By nature, open-ended questions (of which "how can this code be improved?" is an example) cannot be answered *in full*.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure this code is actually valid Python. See https://ideone.com/oS91g7 throwing a SyntaxError -- is there a reason you're separately testing for the `N` case, instead of just falling through to `'skip'` if the `Y` test failed?

Comment: I have edited the answer, should work fine now.